# Entity Framework Code First custom join

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have a Customers table, and an Addresses table.  Customers can have many addresses, but they also have one which is marked as their primary address (if they have any addresses).

Is there some sort of way in code first where I can put a field in the Customer POCO called "PrimaryAddress", and use something like Customers.Include(customer => customer.PrimaryAddress) to just pick up the address which is related to the customer AND has the primary bit set?

I presume the next best thing would be just to write a view in SQL which does the custom join?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is directly possible. If you map something it will end up either as relation or column. So if you expect your customer to look like:

```
public class Customer
{
    ...
    public Address PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

It will end up as the table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customers
(
    ...
    PrimaryAddress_ID INT NULL
)
```

Depending on `Address` entity definition you will either have `Addresses` mapped as 1:N (`Customer_ID` in `Addresse`s table or M:N (junction table) relation.

This is not very good because there should also be some constraint that `PrimaryAddress_ID` must be from addresses related to customer. Such constrain will probably need to be checked by a trigger.

View is also not way to go unless you are building readonly application or you are ready to define INSTEAD OF triggers.

**You can do it without mapping:**

```
public class Customer
{
    ...
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Address PrimaryAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return Addresses.Single(a => a.IsPrimary);
        }
        // If you need set you can implement it in similar way
    }
}
```

You can also define it without attribute but you need to use `Ignore` on `OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
        .Ignore(c => c.PrimaryAddress);
}
```

The disadvantage of the approach is that it will always load all addresses.

In case you know that you will not need other then primary address you can use:

```
context.Entry<Customer(customer)
    .Collection(c => c.Addresses)
    .Query()
    .Where(a => a.IsPrimary)
    .Load();
```

This will load only primary address but you must load Customer first so you will have to roundrips to database.

Comment: Thanks, there is some interesting stuff there.  I should have mentioned that the table was already in the database so I'm not worried about the code generation side of things, but I learnt several new things from your post!  I may still use a view though since it is for search results only and I'm not sure I like the idea of multiple round trips.